# Compile HQL string with eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, compiler-errors, hql

is it possible to compile HQL ? please find my below code :

```
  Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery("select t from MyEntity t where t.myField = :myFieldID");
```

for example throw a compilation error on the above code line when i delete **myField** from **MyEntity**.

What i have found is not possible because the HQL is a string and eclipse cannot compile the string and detect if there is a problem 
The using of NamedQuery not useful because its executed during the application starting and not during the compilation process.

Does any one has another idea to discover the error during the compilation
Thank you

Comment: enable this property hibernate.show_sql=true to see the hql as sql statement in the log file.

Comment: i'm not looking for displaying the sql request, i m trying to find if is possible to discover the error while coding my HQL